# How to use a folder which is in the same Project without adding it to the classpath?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a Plug-in Project.

Its structure is like this:

- ProjectName

  - src

    - MyCode.java
  - css
  - icons
  - myFolder

So, I want to make use of this *myFolder* as a resource in the *MyCode.java* file.

How do I find the folder *myFolder* **without** adding it to the classpath?

Using **getClass().getResource("myFolder")** would require *myFolder* be in classpath, right?

I also **cannot** use

```
new File(MyCode.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile()).getParent()
```

to get the Project Name, as the output of the above line will change depending on the system it is used in, right?

Comment: Why do you want myFolder out of classpath? It is something like finding a folder without a reference point.

Comment: @asg Because if I include it in classpath, that folder gives error as it does not have legitimate file extensions. So if I get that folder as a resource, I can edit the file names with their extensions.

Comment: I mean, myFolder has further files and folders which do not have legitimate file extensions

Comment: How about packaging myFolder as a different entity altogether (like Jar) and making it available to your plugin?

Comment: Oh okay, Can you tell me how to do that? How to make it available to the plugin?

Comment: Is it not possible for you to use `myFolder` directly? It might not be needed in the classpath, but it is in the current working directory. So, you should be able to access it directly..

Comment: @anacron If I use System.getProperty("user.dir"), I get /eclipse as the current working directory but my workspace is somewhere else. Can you tell me how to get into the project folder? I'm new to all this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For an Eclipse plugin you just add the folder to the `build.properties` for the plugin.

You then access the contents of the folder using the `FileLocator` class:

```
Bundle bundle = .... your plugin's bundle

IPath path = new Path("myFolder/xxxxxx");

URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, path, null);

URL fileUrl = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);
```

The URL from `FileLocator.find` uses a special Eclipse protocol but is OK to use if you just want to call `openStream`.

The URL from `FileLocator.toFileURL` can be used to access the object as a file. Calling this may cause Eclipse to unpack the plugin jar to a temporary location.